# JQuery - just walk in main li elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

If I have example

```js
// So, I just want to walk into the main nodes... the code below

$('ul.treeview').children('li').each(
```

```html
<ul class="treeview">
  <li> Something </li>
  <li> Anything
    <ul>
      <li> Anything 2 </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li> Another thing </li>
</ul>
```

...

Shows even the Anything 2 in the walkthrough...

I just want to capture the main nodes in the UL... in this case

Something
Anything
Another thing

Noob question but, didn't figure out how to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code segment grabs all `li`s that are nested in the target. Im pretty sure `$("ul.treeview > li")` will do the trick.

Comment: avoid using css selectors

Answer (score 1):

Make it simple with CSS selector directly :)

```
$('ul.treeview > li').each(
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Jquery **Child Selector** (“parent > child”)

Selects all direct child elements specified by “child” of elements specified by “parent”.

In your case it should be `$('ul.treeview>li')`. Then you can add some filter in the `each()` function to filter `li`.

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to use css selectors just use traversing method .

```js
$(function(){

$('.treeview').children('li').each(function(){
 $(this).addClass('onlyFirstNodes'); 
});

});
```